# Local loading of images in actionscript fails in a browser works in flash player

Tags: image, flash, actionscript, loading, local

This one is strange

When I run the flash player (from flashdevelop) the images are loaded and everything is fine.
But when I run the swf from a browser the requests are sent (using chrome's tools for programers - network tab) but nothing is loaded. The size/content column shows 0/actual size of the file 
This makes me sad.

Any ideas where to look for an answer?

Comment: quote"run the swf from a browser the requests are sent" is this only chrome or mozilla,internet explorer aswell you are  recieving the error?   add your code that request the loader. So we can look at why this is happening. I will say its something to do with filepaths

Comment: ff also doesn't work not sure how to check why. No visible error. I'm starting to think that the problem might be in security. Because if it was a path/code problem then it wouldn't work in flash player. But it works in it. I'll add the code later. 
http://i44.tinypic.com/js13li.jpg
hmm now that i think of it it does load the xml because it's the place where path to .png are stored (in previous version those links were http links now i'm trying to load images from hdd not the web)
Thanks for replaying!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you either compile the swf with the bitmaps imported in your stage/library or make sure that the html version has the right directory setup when the bitmaps are loaded from other directories

Comment: 1) The whole point is that I don't know the files that will be used at the time of compilation. Change files in the folder and don't worry about changing the swf.
2) what dou you mean could you elaborate? I just run the swf file in chrome.